# Codeigniter Single Image into Multiple Resize ie 350*250, 50*50 and original size

Tags: codeigniter

I am new to CodeIgniter. This is what I want to do:

1. Resize the product image into 350*250, 50*50 and origional image while uploading the image in add product from admin.
2. All these three images in the three different folders.

   Here is my code-

   ```
   public function products()
   {
       $config=array();
       $config['upload_path']="./uploads/";
       $config['allowed_types']="jpg|jpeg|gif|png";
       $this->load->library('upload',$config);
       $this->upload->initialize($config);
       if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) 
       {
           $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());                
       }
       else 
       {              
           $file_data = $this->upload->data();
           $data1['img']=base_url().'images/'.$file_data['file_name'];
           $data_image = array(
                   'agenda_id' => $this->input->post('agenda_id'),
                   'file'      => $file_data['file_name']
           );

         $config['image_library']='gd2';
         $config['source_image']='./uploads/'.$file_data["file_name"];
         $config['create_thumb']=FALSE;
         $config['maintain_ratio']=FALSE;
         $config['quality']='60%';                   
         $config['width']=350;
         $config['height']=250;
         $config['new_image']='./uploads350/'.$file_data["file_name"];
         $this->upload->initialize($config);
         $this->load->library('image_lib',$config);
         $this->image_lib->resize();
        }  
        $this->load->model("Admin_model");
        $data= array(
          "Type" =>$this->input->post("Type"),
          "Brand" =>$this->input->post("Brand"),
          "Product_Name" =>$this->input->post("Product_Name"),
          "Price" =>$this->input->post("Price"),
          "Image"=>$data_image['file']

       );
       $this->Admin_model->admin($data);

       $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Product added successfully');

       redirect('Admin/product_list');    
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work fine (haven't tested).  Just make sure the folders exist. Also, if I were you I'd probably keep everything in the same folder and just prepend the size afterwords like `some_image_50.jpg`:

```
public function products() {
        $config = array();
        $config['upload_path'] = "./uploads/";
        $config['allowed_types'] = "jpg|jpeg|gif|png";
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors()); // do something with this...
            // e.g. show_error($this->upload->display_errors());
        } else {
            $file_data = $this->upload->data();
            $data1['img'] = base_url() . 'images/' . $file_data['file_name'];
            $data_image = array(
                'agenda_id' => $this->input->post('agenda_id'),
                'file' => $file_data['file_name']
            );
            //$config['image_library'] = 'gd2'; (default; not needed)
            $this->load->library('image_lib');
            $cfg['source_image'] = './uploads/' . $file_data["file_name"];
            $cfg['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
            $cfg['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
            $cfg['quality'] = '60%';
            $cfg['width'] = 350;
            $cfg['height'] = 250;
            $cfg['new_image'] = './uploads350/' . $file_data["file_name"];
            //$this->upload->initialize($config); why??
            $this->image_lib->initialize($cfg);
            $this->image_lib->resize();
            // the following vars will override certain vars above and keep the ones we haven't overridden
            $cfg['width'] = 50;
            $cfg['height'] = 50;
            $cfg['new_image'] = './uploads50/' . $file_data["file_name"]; // make sure folder exists
            $this->image_lib->initialize($cfg);
            $this->image_lib->resize();
        }
        $this->load->model("Admin_model");
        $data = array(
            "Type" => $this->input->post("Type"),
            "Brand" => $this->input->post("Brand"),
            "Product_Name" => $this->input->post("Product_Name"),
            "Price" => $this->input->post("Price"),
            "Image" => $data_image['file']
        );
        $this->Admin_model->admin($data);

        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Product added successfully');

        redirect('Admin/product_list');
    }
```